# How to use Java interfaces with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an interface and three classes which implements that interface and i should use Hibernate framework to save them to the database. The problem is that, it should create different tables depending on one of the three classes. For example,

```
interface Vehicle;
class Truck;
class Bus;
class Motorbike;

Vehicle vehicle = new Truck(); // In that case, Truck table should be generated
session.save(vehicle); // In that case, Truck table should be generated

Vehicle vehicle = new Bus(); 
session.save(vehicle); // In that case, Bus table should be generated

Vehicle vehicle = new Motorbike(); 
session.save(vehicle); // In that case, Motorbike table should be generated
```

How can i do this with annotations? Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Just use it as you use any other class with hibernate. Nothing seems to be odd here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate inspects your classes at runtime, so it doesn't matter whether you refer to your object by class or by interface.

Note that it won't create tables when you call `session.save()`. It will insert records in the already existing tables. If you want tables created by hibernate, look for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`

Comment: I solved it by adding "@MappedSuperclass" to the top of abstract class. Thank you.

Comment: ok, you solved what I didn't understand you had as a problem. For the next time - include the exact problem in the question description